# Networkx: Use common function for edge weight calculation

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

Suppose I have a function `euc_2d(graph, n1, n2)` that calculates the euclidean distance between two nodes of the same graph. Each nodes has a given `pos=(x,y)` which is assigned on graph creation.

NetworkX provides a function to get the total weight of all edges of a graph namely `graph.size(weight='weight')`. The problem with this method is that it assumes that whenever I add an edge I should explicitly assign the appropriate edge weight like `graph.add_edge(u,v,weight=?)` using a lambda function for example.

However this is very inconvenient (and verbose) since I keep adding and removing edges in the graph all the time.

So, is there a pythonic way I can tell NetworkX to transparently use the `euc_2d()` whenever I ask the total weight of the graph?

Answer (score 2):

Neither `graph.size` nor `graph.add_edge` uses a function to evaluate the weight, they just store values with a given key. To make it easier to work with, just define a function to add an edge with the appropriate weight:

```
def add_euc2d_edge(graph, u, v):
    graph.add_edge(u, v, weight=euc_2d(graph, u, v))
```